# Why is a pointer increment statement optimized away?

Tags: c++, optimization, embedded

I've written a method to parse strings from a GPS but for some reason, a key line is optimized away when not using `-O0`. The method code is as follows:

```
bool Gps::ParsePMTK_ACK(PmtkAck_t &dst, uint8_t *buf, int32_t size)
{    
    // Verify message ID
    uint8_t *pCur = buf;

    memset(&dst, 0, sizeof(dst));

    if (strncmp((char*)pCur, "$PMTK001", 8) != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    pCur = pCur + 8; // <--- This line gets optimized away when not on -O0
                     //      thus causing the pointer to NOT be incremented

    if (*pCur != SEPARATOR) {
        return false;
    }

    ++pCur; // <--- Not optimized away

    if (ProcessInt(dst.cmd, &pCur) != 1) {
        return false;
    }

    int16_t tmp;

    if (ProcessInt(tmp, &pCur) != 1) {
        return false;
    }

    dst.flag = static_cast<AckFlag_t>(tmp);

    return true;
} // end ParsePMTK_ACK
```

When this line is removed, the function fails to process a well formed message because `pCur==buf` at the `if (*pCur != SEPARATOR)` conditional. Thus the function returns `false` on a well formed message because the pointer is pointing to the wrong character when the if statement is reached.

Why is the indicated line removed entirely by the optimizer? Is there a better way to implement thus such that I achieve the desired behavior (i.e., a pointer that gets incremented) even when the optimizer is enabled?

Comment: How do you know that the pointer doesn't get incremented? Where do you read it?

Comment: Using a debugger I can see that pCur is set to the same value as buf at when the `if (*pCur != SEPARATOR)` gets executed. Moreover, when presented with a well formed message, the code fails as the SEPARATOR character is not found due to the pointer not being incremented.

Comment: I updated the post to clarify the problem.

Comment: How this code is called? What is passed as `buf`?

Comment: The first claim (`pCur` wasn't changed) is quite plausible.  A good optimizer **should** do that, despite how it confuses you when you were debugging.  The second claim (the SEPERATOR is in the correct place but not recognized) is not plausible.  The optimizer has adjusted the `*pCur` in your code to compensate for not changing `pCur` and you are confused about where the SEPERATOR is in your input.

Comment: Code is called as follows: `myGps.ParsePMTK_ACK(ackMsg, rxBuffer, rxSize);` where `rxBuffer` is of type `uint8_t*` and `rxSize` is `int32_t`

Comment: What is the size of `rxBuffer`? What are the values?

Comment: The fact that `"$PMTK001"` is 8 characters and you use 6 is a hint at what you are confused about (but well short of proof).  Maybe you intend  `"$PMTK001"` an an inefficient way of coding `"$PMTK0"` but more likely you have `6` (in two places) as an incorrect way of coding `8`

Comment: @JSF Good catch. Fixed the code (both in post and in my project) but the statement in question still disappears.

Comment: No one doubted that the optimizer removed that line of code.  The optimizer **should** remove it and make changes to subsequent uses of `pCur` to balance having removed it.  The question remains whether the SEPERATOR is really where you think it is.  You used to think `buf[6]`, now you think `buf[8]` but where is it actually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose the compiler transforms your original code :

```
pCur = pCur + 8; // <--- This line gets optimized away when not on -O0
                 //      thus causing the pointer to NOT be incremented

if (*pCur != SEPARATOR) {
    return false;
}

++pCur; // <--- Not optimized away
```

into something like this:

```
if (*(pCur + 8) != SEPARATOR) {
    return false;
}

pCur += 9;
```

thus causing confusion while debugging.

Comment: I looked in the disassembly and found that you are indeed correct; that is exactly what is happening behind the scene. @JSF pointed out that I originally had the incorrect value of 6 (as opposed to 8) in my code which masked the problem.

Comment: When debugging optimized code you often get this type of problems.